# How to return URLs for the current directory (“.”), parent directory (“..”)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to list all the contents of the user's document directory in a tableView including the current directory (“.”) and parent directory (“..”).

Its working fine but it does not show the current and parent directory.

For testing reasons i wrote the following code:

```
if let enumerator = fileManager.enumerator(at: URL(string: documentsPath)!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [], errorHandler: nil)
        {
            for item in enumerator{
                print(item)
            }
        }
```

So how can i list the current and parent directory?

Any help is highly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but in case someone is browsing; you can use the URLResourceKey to get this information:

```
func simpleReadDirectoryClean(path: String)  {
    //where path looks like "FolderInMyBundle/Docs"

    let fm = FileManager.default

    let resourceKeys : [URLResourceKey] = [.nameKey, .isDirectoryKey, .parentDirectoryURLKey]
    let bundleURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent(path)

    let enumerator = fm.enumerator(at: bundleURL!, includingPropertiesForKeys: resourceKeys)!

    for case let item as URL in enumerator {
        let resourceInfo = try? item.resourceValues(forKeys: Set(resourceKeys))

        print("-------------- under folder \(path)")
        print("******\(resourceInfo!.isDirectory! ? "Folder" : "File"): \(item.lastPathComponent)")
        print("Parent folder name: \(String(describing: resourceInfo!.parentDirectory?.lastPathComponent))")
        print("Parent folder full path: \(String(describing: resourceInfo!.parentDirectory))")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

**Swift**

```
var pathStr: String = "/path/abc"
let fileURL: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathStr)
let parentUrl = fileURL.deletingLastPathComponent()
print("Parent Directory url : \(parentUrl)")
```

Note: Nevermind swift syntax.

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *pathStr = @"/path/abc";
NSURL *parentUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [pathStr stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]]];
NSLog(@"Parent Directory url: %@",parentUrl);
```

Comment: With this code I can switch to the paret directory, but this is not what i wanted. I'm looking for a solution to really print out `".."` (parent directory) and `"."` (current directory) in the console (or then finally in my tableView)

Comment: Ohh i see , You mean if user click **cd .**   or  **cd ..** like terminal behaviour ?

Comment: To make it more clear: Remember the terminal command ´ls -la´ it shows the ´.´ and ´..´ for the current and parent directory. EDIT: Yes thats what i mean :-)

Comment: I still can't find a solution, does anyone has an idea?